# How to specify type based on runtime condition

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am using mypy and protocols and have run into a spot where I would like type hinting if possible, but I am unable to figure out how I should set it up so mypy doesn't error.

Consider the following example:

```py
class TProtocol(Protocol):
    t: str

@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class T:
    t: str
    t2: str

@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class T2:
    t: str

def func(var: TProtocol) -> None:
    if some_condition:
        var: T
        reveal_type(var)
    else:
        reveal_type(var)
```

While very contrived, it illustrates my goal of I have some runtime condition that if met I know that the type of that variable based on knowledge of the code base. I then want to pass this knowledge onto mypy so that further type checking uses that type.

The same example can be replace with a Union. Some runtime check occurs which tells me explicitly which one of the types I have based on knowledge of the code base. I then want to tell mypy explicitly which type that is for further type checking based on that outside knowledge.

The above example raises an error stating that var is already defined. I tried the `allow_redefinition` option and it didn't change the output.

Comment: In how far is this related to ``Protocol``? It seems you want to specify a type for a given runtime branch. Note that ``hasattr(var, "t2")`` is a runtime expression, and there is nothing preventing a value of type ``T2`` from having a field ``t2``.

Comment: You are right there is nothing explicitly stopping you from adding a field t2 to T2. In the real code, it uses enums instead of `hasattr` and the protocol is actually a field on an object. Based on the enum which is another property on the object I know explicitly what the concrete class of the protocol is. I was attempting to use this knowledge and explicitly type it so the code inside of the if block could be easily type checked. I was hoping to remove the detailed semantics of the code with a more focused example on the problem.

Comment: A protocol doesn't have *one* concrete class. That's the point. Any class that satisfies the protocol is valid, even those you did not define. Perhaps you should update your question to actually match the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You are right, a protocol doesn't have one implementation but based off of some condition I explicitly know the one concrete class it could be in that code base. I essentially have an `isinstance` style of  knowledge about the type. I updated the question to remove the `hasattr` to try and more explicitly show from other means I know the implementation of the protocol that `var` has to be and I would like to type it explicitly as that type. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Some confusing here: 1) The protocol means *all* types that satisfy it are supported.  It does not matter if you intend to use only *some* concrete types, you explicitly annotated it to mean *all* matching types. 2) ``somecondition`` and ``hasattr`` are *runtime* checks performed on the instance. They reveal nothing about the type. 3) If you want it to be some concrete type, why don't you annotate it as such? ``Union[T, T2]`` seems more appropriate.

Comment: all conditions are supported, its a situation of I only accept things that meet this protocol. You are correct that condition is a runtime check and by itself it has nothing to do with typing. But in this case, knowing the code base its apart of I know if that condition is met it will be of some type. That type could be concrete, it could be a sub protocol or it could be a generic. I know during development that the variable type is more defined by meeting the condition than mypy knows and I am trying to use that knowledge so during type checking of further code it can use that fact.

Comment: The same question can be asked of unions of concretes instead of protocols, if I accept a union of T and T2, some condition is met in my code that I know then specifies in it is either T or T2 how can I tell mypy of that fact without using an `isinstance` check because that does not work for things like generic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) to forcefully declare a variable as a specific type. This disregards any other typing information, and works on runtime-branches as well.

```
def func(var: TProtocol) -> None:
    reveal_type(var)         # line 21
    if some_condition:
        var = cast(T, var)   # line 23
        reveal_type(var)
    else:
        var = cast(T2, var)  # line 26
        reveal_type(var)
```

This makes `mypy` treat each casted occurrence of `var` differently, i.e. before and inside each branch:

```
type_tests.py:21: note: Revealed type is 'type_tests.TProtocol'
type_tests.py:24: note: Revealed type is 'type_tests.T'
type_tests.py:27: note: Revealed type is 'type_tests.T2'
```

Comment: I must have something else going on with my real code base is this works as expected with my example. Thanks for your assistance and getting me pointed in the right direction. It is not as pretty as defining variables for a loop but it does the job and that is what matters.